# unable to skip first data value from each row using filter, map or skip operators of Rxjs library in Angular

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs, pipe

How to skip specific data value(full name) from service before subscribe using filter, map or skip operators of Rxjs library in Angular

Basically, I just need to use operators before subscribe the service to get required data and skip some data values

```
this.employee-service.my-Service(page-Number-And-Records-Per-Page)
          .pipe(skip(1),)
          .subscribe(
          //https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4
            (res) => {
              console.log(res.data);
              this.employees = res.data;
              this.sorting(); //A-Z is default
          }
          );
```

[image]

One more try to filter gender with 0 'male' related records only before subscribe, but not working
[image]

Comment: You can use `filter()` for that if I understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array filter on your response data

```
this.employee-service.my-Service(page-Number-And-Records-Per-Page)
          .pipe(map(res=>res.data.filter(obj=>obj.gender===0))))
```

Comment: can you please share working example with stackblitz?

Comment: question updated, please respond accordingly

Comment: this.employee-service.my-Service return res.data. as array. right?

Comment: yes Array(20)
0: {id: "1205", fullName: "some value", shortName: "ak", gender: "0", department: "fgiufioguf iuiou", …}1:{...}2:{...} ...

Comment: in your code you are applying filter to the observable not the array that's why it's not work. If you observable returns a res.data as array then you should do the array filtering in `map` operator

Comment: filter is working after subscribe the service/observable, but not before subscribe. Can we use filter before subscribe?

Comment: Data is available in subscribe((res:any) => {this.employees = res.data.filter((item: any) => item.gender == 0);}) filter is working inside in subscribe() on data.

Comment: Rxjs filter() is to filter out a stream emission with certain condition, which is different from array filter. In your case, your emission return an res object which has  res.data as array, what you have to filter is this array. With my modified answer, you use `map` with array `filter`, which should gives you the correct return in subscribe()

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter to filtering our index or your value , in this case you need to filter index so just add

```
.pipe(filter((val, index) => index > 0))
```

or you can filter your response data as well

```
.pipe(
map(arr=>arr.filter(item=>item.name!=='filterName')))
```

Comment: can you please share working example with stackblitz?

Comment: question updated, please respond accordingly